# Detect if fragment is truly visible in OnResume when being popped from backstack

Tags: android, fragment, android-lifecycle, onresume, back-stack

Imagine the following scenario:

1. Push Fragment A onto BackStack
2. Push Fragment B onto BackStack
3. Push Fragment C onto BackStack

Fragment B tries to make a async web request when its onResume is method is called.

Fragment C has a button called "Clear Backstack" that clears the backstack by calling popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE).

When PopBackStackImmediate is called it pops the Fragments off one by one until the stack is cleared.  As each fragment is popped the fragment's onResume method is called.  For Fragment B, I don't want the async web request to trigger since its going to be immediately destroyed/removed after its popped (because the entire backstack is being cleared).

In this case how can I detect if the entire backstack is being collapsed and skip the async web request on Fragment B in the OnResume method?  Note: I'd still want the async web request to execute if Fragment B is popped/displayed by using the Back button.

Note: I'm using the latest compatibility/support library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

Have you determined  what other lifecycle methods are being called - if it's only on resume, then move the async call further down in the lifecyle (onCreateView or onAttach for example) so that it's only called when moving through it in the normal manner.

Option 2:

When onResume is called you could do a getFragmentByTag on the fragment which has already been destroyed.  If this is null you could then assume that the operation in action is the destruction.

This one seems pretty ugly to me.

Option 3:

Have C pass some flag up to the controlling activity (we'll call it Main), move the async call up, and when B wants to do the web request, have it call up to main to do so.  If C has set the "I'm Destroying" flag, then don't perform the request.

Comment: Option #1 didn't work.
I've implemented something similar to Option #3 and its working ok but I was wondering if there's a simpler way.  I'll leave the question open for awhile and will accept your's as answer if no better alternative arises.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** I was previously removing the old fragment and then adding the new fragment using FragmentTransaction.remove and FragmentTransaction.add respectively.  Switching to FragmentTransaction.replace solved most of my problems when working with the backstack.  See below:

The Android documentation has this to say about FragmentTransaction.replace:

*Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.*

I found the documentation to be slightly misleading because there is an important difference between replace vs. remove+add when the backstack is involved:

If the backstack A->B->C is built using remove+add, then popped back to fragment A, then fragment B's onResume method will be triggered.
If the backstack A->B->C is build using replace, then popped back to fragment A, then fragment B's onResume method will NOT be triggered.